# sqlite query current time and timestamp

Tags: java, sql, database, sqlite

I have a table in my sqlite3 databse which has the following fields:

```
id text not null, phonenum text not null, timeofcall text not null
```

The timestamp is basically the time of the insertion (in my app when a person calls it inserts the tele number and also the time of the call.)

I want to get all of the rows for a particular number within the last minute, something like:

```
SELECT * FROM callstbl WHERE phonenum = '07857463756' AND timeofcall < 1 minute ago;
```

How is something like this accomplished?

EDIT:

when i use this query as suggest by the top poster I get back every row that matches the 'phonenum', its like its ignoring the time function

```
String sql = "select * FROM callstbl WHERE timeofcall >= datetime('now', '-1 minutes') AND phonenum='"+num+"'";
```

The format of my date-time string (timeofcall) is yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

if i just do

```
SELECT * FROM callstbl WHERE timeofcall >= datetime('now', '-1 minutes');
```

I get back every row in the database.

Comment: why is `timeofcall` stored as `text`?

Comment: from what i have seen sqlite is 'loosely typed'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest its better to have a column say, **timeOfCallMili** in your table which stores the time in Miliseconds. This way it will be much easier for you to query based on date/time.
Your query will be something like

```
WHERE timeOfCallMili >= System.currentTimeMillis() - 60000
```

or say you want to get the records within 7 days old (or any specific date for that matter), you could just use a Calendar object to represent that date/time.

```
Calendar queryTime = Calendar.getInstance(); //this instance gets the current date/time as default values
    queryTime.set(Calendar.DATE, queryTime.get(Calendar.DATE) - 7); //setting date to 7 days back
    queryTime.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);    //setting time to 0, as its set to current time by default. 
    queryTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
```

So now your query becomes

```
     WHERE timeOfCallMili >= queryTime.getTimeInMillis();
```

This way you get full flexibility on any type of time based query.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `timeofcall` is in [a format that SQLite understands](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), use:

```
... WHERE timeofcall >= datetime('now', '-1 minutes')
```

Comment: in my java I have this: String sql = "select * FROM callstbl WHERE timeofcall >= datetime('now', '-1 minutes') AND phonenum='"+num+"'";

Comment: when i use that query it returns every row where phonenum matches, its as though its treating the 'AND' as if it was 'OR'

Comment: thanks for the help, i marked the other as correct since he had more platform specific info for me too, +1